# Querying for exact match in Kibana

Tags: kibana

In my Kibana, when I search my document I need to look for exact match:
In my document I have a field named message.

So If I search (Using Kibana) something like:

> message: "Provider replied with error code 2006"

I get all the documents that have one instance of those words.
I would like to have exact match.

I am running Kibana: 5.3.2. and Elasticsearch is 5.3.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Elasticsearch are two Types of "Strings".

- Keyword:

  > They are typically used for filtering (Find me all blog posts where status is published), for sorting, and for aggregations. Keyword
  >   fields are only searchable by their exact value.

  [See the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/keyword.html)
- Text

  > field to index full-text values, such as the body of an email or the description of a product. These fields are analyzed, that is they are passed through an analyzer to convert the string into a list of individual terms before being indexed.

  [See the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/text.html)

Sometimes it is possible to access to the Keyword by adding ".keyword" to your field. So try this one:

```
message.keyword: "Provider replied with error code 2006"
```

Otherwise you have to check your mapping and change it to Keyword.